# ¿Se puede reciclar un activity para usarlo en varios activities en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

Estoy realizando un proyecto de una app que habra un boton hacer un nuevo registro, la app tiene como activity principal el listado de datos en listview al darle click me aparece el activity anterior pero para actualizar. SqlLite

Comment: Quieres copiar toda la actividad para hacer varias copias o quieres hacer una llamada al xml de la actividad que quieres reciclar?

Comment: El activity es el mismo que para guardar y actualizar, lo que pasa es que quiero saber si hay una forma de utilizar un solo activity para las dos operaciones y no estar creando otra, tanto el xml como el java.

Comment: Pues por supuesto que la hay. Simplemente creando un método en el cual le digas que si el resultado 'lo obtienes con un `Bundle`' o pulsación es para ingresar datos 'insertas un item', o si no haces un update valiendote del mismo xml 'de sus campos'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes pasar un parámetro a tu `activity` al invocarlo para saber si la operación es de creación o actualización.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("crear", Boolean.TRUE); //crear o actualizar
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Desde tu `activity` recoges el parámetro y ya sabes si quieres crear o actualizar.